# Ambiguous ErrorQuotaExceeded message when using Microsoft Graph REST APIs

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi

My current team has developed an application that interfaces with Microsoft Graph APIs in order to interact with Outlook emails from our enterprise portal.
Ultimately the REST API's has returned an unexpected amount of errors to multiple users, mentioning "ErrorQuotaExceeded" as the error code.
That's an extremely ambiguous message since none of the involved users has space quota issues. Also, this error only appears when calling some specific REST endpoints.

For instance, the following request always works, returning a payload with HTTP 200 response status, as expected:

**GET** `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailFolders/Inbox/messages`

However, if we try to synchronize the user emails adding `/delta` to the aforementioned GET request ([as mentioned by the official docs](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/delta_query_messages)), we get the following error, with HTTP 403 status code:

**GET** `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailFolders/Inbox/messages/delta`

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "ErrorQuotaExceeded",
        "message": "Mailbox has exceeded maximum mailbox size.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "13c686c6-5d4d-4a9b-8594-3b34482d6805",
            "date": "2018-11-13T08:09:12"
        }
    }
}
```

It should be noted that I have 3.27GB occupied out of 50GB, so it wouldn't make any sense to me that the ErrorQuotaExceeded error gets triggered.

The official Microsoft Graph Support page explicitly recommends asking this kind of questions to StackOverflow, since they don't seem to offer an official support to their API. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: How many messages are in your Inbox? From the looks of things on our side, the issue is going over the allowed number of messages in a single folder.

Comment: Hi Jason, thanks for replying. I have 33 messages in the `received` folders, and 7 in the `sent` folder. I don't have any draft or deleted mail. Also, I didn't create any custom folders. So maybe it's something else

Comment: Well, for that particular request id, the error happened because the mailbox database could not save the sync state into the folder. The error returned by the mailbox store indicated that the messages per folder quota was exceeded. It seems odd that 40 or so messages are taking 3.27 GB of space, I wonder if there's something going on with that particular mailbox. In any event, you can get assisted support for Graph through Developer Support, options here: https://developer.microsoft.com/office/docs, see the "Office assisted support" section.

Comment: Thank you Jason, we're going to inspect forward this on our end and use Developer Support if deemed necessary.